# Flower versus Florist?

Tags: orthography

As a very bad speller I love to find justification for my lack of ability.  I'm wondering about the reasoning/history that 'Flower' and 'Florist' have such different spelling.  I'm guessing it has something to do with 'flow' where a flower is a thing which flows and it would be too much to have a person working with such things be a flowerer.  Any better explanations?

Comment: As @suməlic says, look at their etymologies: **Florist**: 1620s, formed on analogy of French *fleuriste*, from Latin *floris*, genitive of *flos* "flower" (see flora) + -ist. c. 1200; **Flower**: from Old French *flor* "flower, blossom", from Latin *florem* (nominative *flos*) "flower". Anyway, to ask a question on EL&U, you must include **research** or it is off-topic.

Comment: Flower came into English from French around 1200, early enough to be affected by the [Great Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift). The Middle English pronunciation /fluːr/ would have given rise to our present pronunciation of *flower*. And, probably not entirely coincidentally, the OED says one of the spellings of *flower* in Middle English was *flur*. *Florist* came into English from French around 1600, after much of the Great Vowel Shift had happened. So they have different vowels, and thus different spellings.

Comment: I apologize as I haven't use this stackexchange.  Feel free to delete or ask me to delete.  Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, they're spelled differently because they have different vowel sounds! *Flower* has more-or-less the same vowel sound as the first syllable of the word "cowrie," which we can transcribe as /aʊ/ (although the following "r" may alter this a bit). "Florist" has the same vowel sound as the first syllable of "glory" or "sorry," depending on accent, which we can transcribe as /ɔ/ or /ɒ/.

The sound /aʊ/ is usually spelled "ou" or "ow", and before the letter r, the sounds /ɔ/ and /ɒ/ are usually spelled "o."

The word *flower* is not related to the verb *flow.* A hint to this is that they have different vowel sounds ("flow" has the /oʊ/ sound of "toe"); these vowel sounds only happen to share the same spelling by coincidence. You can learn its origin by looking it up in the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=flower&allowed_in_frame=0); most general-purpose dictionaries also list etymology. "Flower" comes from *florem,* the accusative form of the Latin word *flos.*

It is related to *florist,* but somewhat indirectly. The pronunciation and spelling of the word *flower* show the effect of several layers of sound changes, some in French (from which we borrowed the word) and some in English. The spelling of the *flor-* part of the word *florist* is taken directly from Latin, and the pronunciation is based on the general English sound-spelling correspondences for the letter "o".

The same alternation between "ow" and "o" exists for pretty much the same reasons in the words *power* and *potency,* which are related to one another.